# Starting new activity with markers on google maps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, geojson

I am not able to make marker a button to open a new activity, I am getting information of the coordinates from `GeoJson` file but and able to get the marker but the marker is not going to new activity.

I have tried `setOnClickListener` and `setOnWindowClickListner` as used in some of the queries but to no avail

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
// entering the google maps setting 
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    ArrayList<LatLng> listPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Sg));
    googleMap.setMinZoomPreference(11);    
    boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.style_json)));    
    if (!success) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
    }

    try {`//getting data from geojson`
        getData();
        JSONObject emptyGeoJson = new JSONObject();
        layerShop = new GeoJsonLayer(googleMap, emptyGeoJson);
        layerFB = new GeoJsonLayer(googleMap, emptyGeoJson);
        layerComm = new GeoJsonLayer(googleMap, emptyGeoJson);
        GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(googleMap, HotspotData);        
        Iterable<GeoJsonFeature> geoJsonFeature = layer.getFeatures();    
        for(GeoJsonFeature cur : geoJsonFeature) {
            String s = cur.getProperty("Description");    
            int begin = s.indexOf("<th>LOCATION_TYPE</th> <td>");
            int end = s.indexOf("</td>",begin);
            String category = s.substring(begin+27,end);    
            if (category.contentEquals("F&B")){
                layerFB.addFeature(cur);
                Log.v("MapsActivity", "So here we are with " + cur);
            }
            else if (category.contentEquals("Shopping Mall")){
                layerShop.addFeature(cur);
            }
            else if (category.contentEquals("Community")){
                layerComm.addFeature(cur);
            }
        }
        layers.put("Community", layerComm);
        layers.put("Cafes", layerFB);
        layers.put("Shopping", layerShop);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
    GeoJsonPointStyle pointStyle = layerFB.getDefaultPointStyle();
    pointStyle.setIcon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(this, R.drawable.ic_wifi));
    pointStyle.setTitle("View information");    
    //Log.v("MapsActivity", "This is layerFB + " + layerFB.getFeatures());
    Iterable<GeoJsonFeature> layerFBfeature = layerFB.getFeatures();
    Iterable<GeoJsonFeature> layerShopfeature = layerShop.getFeatures();
    Iterable<GeoJsonFeature> layerCommfeature = layerComm.getFeatures();    
    Marker marker;
    for(GeoJsonFeature i: layerFBfeature){
        LatLng is = (LatLng)i.getGeometry().getGeometryObject();
        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(is).title("location"));           
    }
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, activity_location.class);
           startActivity(intent);    
           return true;
       }
   });    
}
```

Comment: First validate if your on markerClickListener is working or just put a log or toast message and not sure this is a Activity or fragment if its fragment use getActivity() or requireActivity() fro Intent

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Is `activity_location` an existing, valid activity and did you add it to your Android Manifest?

Try the below code as a working example.

MapsActivity.java

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, HelloWorldActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

HelloWorldActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, "in HelloWorldActivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HelloWorldActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Hope this helps!